# Rails migrate down to reduce String value size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a task where I need to increase the size limit of a String field. I've written the migration that I currently have below.

```
class IncreaseCompanyNumberLimit < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def up
    if Company.columns.find { |c| c.name == 'company_number' }.limit < 25
      change_column :company, :company_number, :string, :limit => 25
    end  
  end

  def down
    change_column :company, :company_number, :string, :limit => 20
  end
end
```

The problem I'm running into is if someone has entered a `company_number` after the `up` method is run during the migration. If the new `company_number` is larger than the 20 limit I'm attempting to set with the `down` method, then it crashes when I run the `down` method because the existing data is too long.

Is there an effective way to trim anything down that is larger than the limit being set by the `down` method? This is a large table so I'm trying to find an efficient way to achieve this, and google hasn't been much help.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: You may need to run a truncate operation using `execute`, like with `LEFT()`.

Comment: What database are you using, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run trim the values as part of the migration. You can use the database's own string handling functions to do this much more efficiently than retrieving the values and trimming in Ruby. These functions are different per-database. I'll use [PostgreSQL's string functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) for this example. You should be able to adapt it to any database.

Do it [in batches](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-in_batches) to avoid locking the whole table while it runs.

```
class IncreaseCompanyNumberLimit < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  NEW_LIMIT = 25
  OLD_LIMIT = 20

  def up
    change_column :company, :company_number, :string, limit: NEW_LIMIT
  end

  def down
    Company.in_batches.update_all("company_number = left(company_number, OLD_LIMIT)")
    change_column :company, :company_number, :string, :limit => OLD_LIMIT
  end
end
```

---

Traditional SQL schema management says to use constraints and limits in the schema to ensure the data conforms. Rails is different. The models and database are inseparable. With an ORM managed schema like this I recommend *against putting business logic in your schema*. Arbitrary field limits are the biggest offenders. As you're learning, they can arbitrarily change. Having to do a schema update because this week the limit is 25 and next week the limit is 20 is an inefficient use of programmer time.

```
class RemoveCompanyNumberLimit < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  NEW_LIMIT = nil
  OLD_LIMIT = 20

  def up
    change_column :company, :company_number, :string, limit: NEW_LIMIT
  end

  def down
    Company.in_batches.update_all("company_number = left(company_number, OLD_LIMIT)")
    change_column :company, :company_number, :string, :limit => OLD_LIMIT
  end
end
```

Instead, enforce this in the Company model with a [validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html). This is more flexible, and it will provide an informative error message.

```
class Company
  validates :company_number, length: { maximum: 25 }
end
```

Then your controller can use the [validation errors](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#working-with-validation-errors) to inform the user what went wrong.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you before your answer was posted, but we use MySQL. I was able to adapt your solution to work in our code, thank you so much for your help!